# Vertex editor panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vertices, nodes

I want to connect two lines in QGIS 3. In QGIS 2.18.16 I fixed it when I edited coordinate values of vertexes instead of manually (with mouse) moving them across the map because I want to match lines exactly. I could change the vertex coordinate values in Vertex editor panel:

[image]

But this panel is not showing in QGIS 3.

Is there any solution how to connect two lines? Like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved! To open Vertex editor panel with coordinates and vertexes I should rightclick on map being in vertex editor mode.

Comment: For me, I can't just right click on the map. I have to right-click on a selected feature on the map to have the option for "Vertex Editor." Is there no way for this to pop up automatically like it did in QGIS 2? That was very convenient!

Answer (score 2):

Project -> snapping options :

Set the layers box to 'active layer' if your points are in the same layer, otherwise 'All layers'

Then select 'Vertex' and close.

When you move your first point close to the second point using the vertex editor, you should now see the pink symbol become a square instead of a cross, which means that snapping will occur, and your points will automatically be set to the same coordinates.

Your approach is also valid but might be more tedious for an increased number of points!